# Nodal admittance matrix of a winding

Tags: electric-machine, winding, nodal-analysis

I have a question concerning the nodal admittance matrix of a winding that has n turns.
If each turn of the winding had its own model, is it possible to consider my winding a n-port network?

Comment: You could probably ... if there were no "interaction" between the elementary model "1 turn"...

Comment: @Antonio51 By interaction you mean, couplings rights? -either capacitive ou inductive-

Comment: Yes. But if all these "couplings" are included in your "N-port model", you can define the base model for the "whole windings" (very complicated thing), not for a part (for each turn).

Comment: @Antonio51 I can easily define the base model for the winding (all turns included) but I am more interested in the turn behavior. I am more confused on whether I can define each turn as a port. I mean does is it physically make sense or it nonsense?

Comment: It does physically make sense ... But probably a "bit" complicated without checking at "lab". See my answer ... A try to modeling...

Comment: @Antonio51 very much understood. Much obliged!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something like this for a "little" inductor (4 turns).
But I do not have all the measuring instruments to evaluate the "consistency" of the model.
However, it can be a "beginning" ...

[image]

Comment: This is a start for me, thank you!

Comment: RF Microelectronics   (Prentice Hall Communications Engineering and Emerging Technologies Series)  Razavi. You should read  "chapter 7".

Comment: Will do, thank you very much Antonio !!